# Почему поведение сборщика мусора в Java считается непредсказуемым?

Tags: java, сборщик-мусора

Интересует вопрос, почему поведение `System.gc()` считается непредсказуемым.
Вопрос с сертификации Java OCA.

Если взять в пример следующую ситуацию:

```java
public class Bear {

    protected void finalize() {
        System.out.println("Roar!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bear bear = new Bear();
        bear = null;
        System.gc();
    } 
}
```

*Roar!* выводится в 100% случаев.

Однако правильным ответом считается утверждение, что *Roar!* может быть как выведен, так и не выведен.

До меня не доходит, почему вдруг **gc** может решить не собирать мусор в данной конкретной ситуации.

Comment: потому что он не обязан. К тому же в Вашем случае он мог отработать и от присваивания null, так и по факту выхода из программы. Просто Вам везет. Если бы программа была бы значительно больше, больше потоков то поведение сильно-сильно бы поменялось.

Comment: @KoVadim насколько я могу помнить, finalize выполняется только при успешном явном вызове System.gc(), т.е. по факту выхода из программы finalize не выполняется никогда. И всё же не понятно что значит "не обязан". Это ведь набор инструкций, который запустится или не запустится при наличии определенных условий (как и любой программный код). Что может произойти, что java решит не собирать мусор при его наличии?

Comment: уточню. gc не обязана чистить память как только Вы позвали system.gc. Внутри кода gc() есть проверка, нужно ли чистить память. Если памяти достаточно, то зачем? Внутри этого вызова может быть очень сложная эвристика. А в одной из версий jvm он был пустой. К примеру, я когда то использовал JMagick (обертка вокруг ImageMagick). И там на базе finalize было организовано освобождение памяти. И оно очень хорошо выжирало 18 гигов памяти в сутки и finalize не вызывался. Но как только вставили паузы (sleep) время от времени, gc запускался и подчищал. Ручной запуск gc время от времени никак не помогал.

Comment: Понятненько. Получается, как вы и сказали, мне просто везло)) Я правильно понимаю, что в любой момент я могу запустить этот самый код, и gc может не выполниться?

Comment: да. все зависит то конкретной реализации gc в данном jvm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В идеале все кажется простым: сборщик мусора обходит все объекты и если объект нигде не имеет ссылок на другие объекты, то он освобождается и вызывается `finalize()`. Возможно так когда то и было, но не сейчас. Такой механизм работы сборщика мусора приводил бы к потере производительности и неоправданным затратам ресурсов.

Поэтому сейчас все работает по другому - используется механизм разделения объектов на поколения (*generations*), согласно этому принципу чем дольше живет объект тем он дольше может прожить. В основе такого принципа лежит простое наблюдение, что большинство Java объектов живут очень короткое время и только малое их количество живет долго - соответственно спрашивается: *а зачем тратить ресурсы на чистку малого количества объектов?*

Сначала все новые объекты попадают в т.н. `eden` (рай), размера рая лимитирован. Как только размер рая переполняется вызывается т.н. `minor collection`, который работает только внутри рая. После чистки объекты которые выжили перемещаются в следующую ступень взросления (aging), в котором сборка мусора происходит чуточку реже - и т.д. Чем дальше объект движется по ступеням взросления - тем он реже подвергается чистке. Объекты которые живут долго подвергаются чистке реже в ходе уже `major collection`. Схематично это можно изобразить таким графиком:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На концепцию *generations* сверху накладываются еще несколько дополнительных ограничений/дополнений:

1. Требования дополнительной памяти
2. Производительность
3. Приоретизация

Собственно говоря, вызов программиста - `System.gc()` - это просьба о повышении приоритета.

**Update**

Как правильно заметили в комментариях здесь описан принцип работы конкретного сборщика мусора, а именно для виртуальной машины [Java Hotspot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot). Другие виртуальные машины (для тех кто в танке их много - [неполный список здесь](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines)) могут использовать другие принципы.

Comment: Отличный ответ!

Comment: Да, спасибо, теперь всё наглядно ясно.

Comment: есть только одна проблема это ответа - он описывает одно из возможных реализаций сборщика мусора. Плюс содержит фактические ошибки. метод finalize вызывается, обычно это делает в отдельном потоке, а то и не одном. К примеру, в андроиде есть два потока, которые над этим трудятся.

Comment: @KoVadim, частично конечно соглашусь. Сборщики мусора постоянно меняются, совершенствуются, тем более, для разных виртуальных машин есть разные сборщики мусора. Скажу даже больше: были как то дискуссии о присоединяемых (внешних) сборщиках мусора. В моем ответе описывается механизм действия сборщика мусора для Hotspot JVM. По-поводу `finalize()` - я и не утверждал, что он в одном потоке :)